# adding links for selecting language in custom control (.ascx) in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, resources, custom-control

From SharePoint UI, at far right top corner, we can change the language of our page, if language packs are installed and if we have used Resources file in our code. But For end users, I want to provide them two links for language selection possibly with small image links with country maps in asp:Label Control or Image Control.

How we can do that ? any example of this type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800886%28v=office.14%29.aspx) has information how does it work and have clear explanation how to customize it.